# TextInput resets after four numbers using onChangeText and value props

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

Whenever I type in four numbers in a text input form, it resets to one number. I am using `toLocaleString()` to format the number as I type, but it is only allowing for four numbers. I am also scaling the font size as the input gets bigger, but I don't know if that matters.

How would I fix this?

This is what I have:

```
const textInputWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width - 50
const maxFontSize = 96

export const TextInput = () => {

const [amount, setAmount] = useState("")
const [fontSize, setFontSize] = React.useState(maxFontSize)

    const scaleFontSize = (width) => {
      const actualWidth = width + fontSize
      const scaledSize = Math.min(maxFontSize, fontSize * (textInputWidth / actualWidth))

      setFontSize(scaledSize)
    }

    const onContentSizeChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
      const { contentSize } = nativeEvent
      const { width } = contentSize

      scaleFontSize(width)
    }

    return (

        <View style={$inputField}>
            <TextInput
              autoFocus={true}
              style={[$inputText, { fontSize }]}
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              onChangeText={(text) => {
                const num = parseInt(text)
                setAmount(num.toLocaleString())
              }}
              onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
              value={amount}
            />
         </View>
     )
}


inputField: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignSelf: "center",
  padding: 15,
}

inputText: {
  width: textInputWidth,
  fontFamily: "Bold",
  fontSize: 96,
  textAlign: "center",
}
```